# block custom date in bootstrap editable datepicker

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I want to use custom disable date block in bootstrap editable date picker.Here is my sample code .

```
<a href="#" class="travel_date" data-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit
</a>
```

Here is bootstrap editable code

```
 $('.travel_date').editable({
           type:  'date',
           pk:    1,
           url:   '/booking/session_store_id',
           name:  'travel_date',
           title: 'Select Travel Date',
           datepicker: {
               startDate: 'tomorrow',
               datesDisabled: '12/25/2017'
           },
           showbuttons:false,
           success: function(data) 
           {
                location.reload();
            },
        });
```